# The Collada 3D model is flashing

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have developed iOS application to have AR functionality using ARKit. I have used [this](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/SamMitiAR-iOS) project.

The application works with Collada (.dae) file dynamically which means the the client uploads the Collada file and all of the textures somewhere and the model gets shown accordingly with the help of [this solution](https://the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/).
The application works mostly fine but for this one we experience the black part of the model flashing.

As you could see in the pictures most of the floor should be completely black(apart from one small part which is black and white). When we zoom in the model (make the model bigger) the model gets shown with less white spots on the floor(in the first picture almost no white spot but sometimes we can see some). When we zoom out and make the model smaller, we see many white spots on the floor and other places which should be black.[zoomed in the model with less white spot][image: ][1][1]] 
[image: zoomed out the model with many white spots on the floor]

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is known as [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

In the given model, the black (bottom/floor) plane and the black/white patterned plane are very close so as the user moves further away the renderer doesn't accurately differentiate which plane should be shown first.

One solution is to set the `readsFromDepthBuffer` property of the plane's materials to false. 
Once you have a reference to the node/plane, you can set the property to its material.

```
if let geom = node.geometry {
    for material in geom.materials {
        material.readsFromDepthBuffer = false
    }
}
```